# Repating y-asix in google chart line graph

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have problem in using  google API. When I have single value on graph, values on y-axis of graph are reparting. Can anybody help me how to solve the issue?
Below is the graph view:

[image]

Graph Code is as follows:

```
function go()
{
    changeDataView();
    hideMessage();

    var view = document.getElementById("thepage:pb:theForm:dataview");
    var obj = document.getElementById("thepage:pb:theForm:object");
    var startDate = document.getElementById("thepage:pb:theForm:startdate");
    var endDate = document.getElementById("thepage:pb:theForm:enddate");
    var group = document.getElementById("thepage:pb:theForm:group_list");
    var member= document.getElementById("thepage:pb:theForm:member_list");
    var member_data = "";

    if(member)
    {
        member_data = member.value
    }

    var time_data= document.getElementById("thepage:pb:theForm:time");
    var time = '';

    if(time_data)
    {
        time = time_data.value;
    }

    var str_start_date = startDate.value;
    var str_start_date_split = str_start_date.split("/");
    str_start_date =str_start_date_split[2]+'-'+str_start_date_split[1]+'-'+str_start_date_split[0];

    var str_end_date = endDate.value;
    var str_end_date_split = str_end_date.split("/");
    str_end_date =str_end_date_split[2]+'-'+str_end_date_split[1]+'-'+str_end_date_split[0];

    var start = new Date(str_start_date);
    var end = new Date(str_end_date);
    var diff = new Date(end - start);
    var days = diff/1000/60/60/24;

    if(days<30 && time=="month")
    {
        alert('Please select days more then 30 for month.');
        return ;
    }
    if(days<7 && time =="week")
    {
        alert('Please select days more then 7 for week.');
        return;
    }
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initCharts);

    function initCharts() {
        AnalyticsController.getChartDataForAssignmentCountGraphs(
                view.value,obj.value,
                startDate.value, endDate.value,
                group.value,member_data, time,
                function(result, event){
            if (typeof result  === 'undefined' || result == null) {
                alert('No data found');
                return ;
            }
            else if(result.length==0)
            {
                alert('No data found');
                return;
            }
            var chartresult = result;

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            AnalyticsController.getMembers(
                    view.value,obj.value,
                    startDate.value, endDate.value,
                    group.value, member_data, time,
                    function(xresult, event){
                if (typeof xresult  === 'undefined' || xresult == null) {
                    return ;
                }
                else if(xresult.length==0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                console.log(xresult);
                data.addColumn('string', 'Assignment Date');

                for(var i =0; i<xresult.length;i++)
                {
                    data.addColumn('number', xresult[i]);
                    console.log('member');
                    console.log(xresult[i]);
                }

                for(var i =0; i<chartresult.length;i++){
                    var r = chartresult[i];
                    var arr = [];

                    arr.push(r.closedate);

                    for(var j =0 ; j < result[i].memberscount.length ; j++)
                    {
                        arr.push(chartresult[i].memberscount[j].count);
                    }
                    console.log('count');
                    console.log(arr);
                    data.addRow(arr);
                }

                var strin = '';
                var sub = '';
                if(view.value == 'AssignmentCountPerGroupView')
                {
                    strin = 'Assignment Count: Per Assignment Group';
                    sub ='Shows Lead/Cases assignment count per time(hour,day,week,month) for multiple Assignment Groups.';
                }
                else if( view.value == 'AssignmentCountPerMemberView')
                {
                    strin = 'Assignment Count: Per Assignment Group Member';
                    sub = 'Shows Leads/Cases assignment count per time(hour,day week,month) for multiple Assignment Group Members.';
                }
                else if(view.value == 'AveragePerMember')
                {
                    strin = 'Average: assigned per member';
                    sub ='Shows a grid listing each member and the total assigned number within the date range and the average per time(hour, day, week, month).';
                }
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        title: strin,
                        subtitle: sub
                    },
                    height: 500,
                    axes: {
                        x: {
                            0: {side: 'top'}
                        }
                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chartBlock2'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            });
        }, {escape:true});
    } // end initCharts()
} // end go()
```

Comment: try adding a `vAxis.format` that includes decimal places, or provide your own `vAxis.ticks`, which don't repeat. see the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for more info...

Comment: Ok thanks!! I will try on it and will let you know!!

Comment: I am using material charts and i found that vaxis.format and vAxix.ticks are not supported.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143

Comment: there is a `theme: 'material'` you can try on a `'corechart'`-- it's close and the other options should work